# Disposing File Object Properly

Tags: c#, service, directory, filestream

Ok so heres the thing. When ever a trigger is hit i append my logs in a specific folder. The code works fine and it appends it correctly but if i try to manually delete the folder from the desktop its giving a "The action cannot be completed cause the folder/file is open in another program";

i guess im not disposing it right but i dont know where i missed it. I know its the folder that is attached to the process cause i tried to delete the .log file inside and it allowed me.

```
 private void LogEvent(string filename,bool AppendTxt,string msg)
    {
        string sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString() + " ==> ";
        msg = sLogFormat + msg;
        // create directory
        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1") != true)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1");
        }
        string dailyLog = "C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1" + "\\" + filename + ".log";
        FileStream FS = null;
        //write or append txt
        if (!AppendTxt)
        {
            if (File.Exists(dailyLog))
            {
                File.Delete(dailyLog);
            }
            using (FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) { }
            FS.Close();
            StreamWriter TXT_WRITE = new StreamWriter(dailyLog);
            TXT_WRITE.WriteLine(msg);
            TXT_WRITE.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!File.Exists(dailyLog))
            {
                  using (FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) { }
                  FS.Close();
            }
            FileStream FSAppend = new FileStream(dailyLog, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter TXT_WRITE = new StreamWriter(FSAppend);
            TXT_WRITE.WriteLine(msg);
            TXT_WRITE.Close();
            FSAppend.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does seem to close the file properly but not in an exception-safe manner.

You also have some unnecessary code in there (like `using (FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) { } FS.Close();` ).

The smallest modification looks like this:

```
    else
    {
        //if (!File.Exists(dailyLog))
        //{
        //      using (FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) { }
        //      FS.Close();
        //}

        using (FileStream FSAppend = new FileStream(dailyLog, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter TXT_WRITE = new StreamWriter(FSAppend))
        {
          TXT_WRITE.WriteLine(msg);
        }
        //TXT_WRITE.Close();
        //FSAppend.Close();
    }
```

But I would rewrite this whole method like:

```
private void LogEvent(string filename,bool AppendTxt,string msg)
{
    string sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + " " 
         + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString() + " ==> ";
    msg = sLogFormat + msg;
    // create directory
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1") != true)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1");
    }
    string dailyLog = "C:\\Users\\DT-Npax\\Desktop\\LOGS1" + "\\" + filename + ".log";

    if (AppendText)
       System.IO.File.AppendAllText(dailylog, msg);
    else 
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dailylog, msg);
}
```

There is no need to pre-create or delete files.

Comment: Tried this but problem is still there. I still cannot delete the LOGS1 folder

Comment: Oh working now. I guess some other process was still holding it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the streams in a using block since they implement `IDisposable`.

I must say this code is a little odd...

```
using (FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) { }
FS.Close();
StreamWriter TXT_WRITE = new StreamWriter(dailyLog);
TXT_WRITE.WriteLine(msg);
TXT_WRITE.Close();
```

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
using (FileStream FS = File.Create(dailyLog)) 
{ 
     using(StreamWriter TXT_WRITE = new StreamWriter(dailyLog))
     {
           TXT_WRITE.WriteLine(msg);
     }
}
```